# Table and \hlines too short or wide

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs

Here is a MWE of what I am trying to do.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l r r r r r r r r r r r}
\toprule
A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 & A5 & A6 & A7 & A8 & A9 & A10 & A11 & A12 \\
\midrule
\rowcolor{blue} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\[0pt]
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l r r r r r r r r r r r r r r}
\toprule
A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 & A5 & A6 & A7 & A8 & A9 & A10 & A11 & A12 & A13 & A14 & A15 \\
\midrule
\rowcolor{blue} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\[0pt]
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The first table has too long `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` and looks weird. I have a few questions about this.

How can I set the size of `tabularx` to be the content width?

How can I set the last column to be aligned to the right (so all columns span over the table)?

How can I set the `\rowcolor` to span over the whole table?

The second table in the example is too wide. Do you know any tricks to make it look better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First table has long rules because `tabularx` is trying to make a table `textwidth`-wide but there is no column with adjustable width. Same for second table, but in this case the table contents exceed the `textwidth`. You need to use `X`-column specifier to allow automatic width adjustment.
Try replacing

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l r r r r r r r r r r r}
```

with

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l *{11}X}
```

Note that `X`-columns are left-aligned and of equal width. To get the last column right-aligned, you can use `r`-column or define a new column type `R` as [follows](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabularx_package),

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
```

Then use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l *{10}X r}` or `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l *{10}X R}` to make the last column right aligned.

To allow for all rows of same color, you can use the `rowcolors` command from `xcolor` package. The `rowcolors` command allows you to have alternating colors for odd and even rows, with the first color specfier for odd rows. You can still use `rowcolor` to change color of specific rows.

An example with modified column-types and coloring.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \rowcolors{1}{gray}{gray}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L *{10}C R}
    \toprule
        A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 & A5 & A6 & A7 & A8 & A9 & A10 & A11 & A12 \\
    \midrule
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\[0pt]
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that all `X`-columns are same width. Adjusting width can be tricky in `tabularx`. Instead try using [`tabulary`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) or [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package.